# What do you call the "cup of fizzy drink" in a trio at a fast food chain?

Tags: word-request

I am pretty sure there's a special term for it, because "paper cup of coke" doesn't sound right, and all of the other words I can think at the moment doesn't sound great. If it doesn't sound great, it's not great for marketing, so I am pretty sure there's a word for it.

Like when you order a Big Mac trio, you get coke, but I don't think the cashiers would call it "a cup of coke".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US, a beverage from a fast food restaurant is simply referred to as "[size] [brand]" or as "[size] drink".

For example, a medium combo might consist of "a burger, medium fries, and a medium Coke."

When not referring to any particular beverage, it would be a "cup", though this may vary by region.

> Can I get a large cup? I'm going to get some ice from the machine.

Comment: It would also be fine to say “a medium-sized drink”, but “a medium drink” is idiomatic.